# Why my PrintWriter doesn't print on console if I don't use PrintWriter(Writer out,boolean autoFlush) constructor?

Tags: java, printwriter

The following code is from another Stack Overflow Thread about difference between PrintStream and PrintWriter.

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class PracticeWriter
 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Method 1");

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
        writer.println("Method 2");

    }
   }
```

However,I added `true` later when I saw it's not printing Method 2 on the console.It's supposed to print using `PrintWriter(Writer out)` constructor.Why it is not doing so?

Comment: The default value for auto-flush is `false`, meaning that you must call `flush()` or `close()` (you don't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flush writes from the buffer to the actual stream; with no closing, flushing or auto-flushing, the lack of output is entirely expected behaviour. Add a call to flush, or use the constructor in the way you have done (with auto-flushing enabled) - or just have a try-with-resources.